# Access C++ COM Interface from C# throws exception in GetIdsOfNames

Tags: c#, com, com-interop

I have a C++ COM object (32 bit). This COM object calls
a C# COM Object and as part of the initialization, passes an interface pointer (IDispatch) to C#. The idea is that the C# code can call back into the C++
COM Object using this interface.
Example: 
C++ calls C# COM method -->

```
OpenService(...., [..MarshalAs..IDispacth])
```

The issue I am having is that when the C# tries to call into that interface
I get MethodNotfound exception.

Internally I declare an interface

```
[Comimport, Guid(...), Interfacetype.Dual]
public interface CallBackInterface
{
    void SOData(int data)
}
```

I cast the given IDispatch pointer to this interface

```
   CallBackInterface cb = (CallbackInterface)inputObject;
   cb.SoData(0);
```

It is that call that gives exception NameNotfound in getIdsOfNames.
The interesting thing is that I got the reflector and tried to debug 
the source. The exception seems to be coming from ComEventsSinks.cs 
but this is not a connection point container or connection point.
I am trying to access the interface given by the calling C++ object.

I gave up and created a simple ATL COM object and I tried to 
accomplish the same, and it works great. I could even to 
what I eventually wanted to do, CoMarshalInterfaceThreadInStream and 
CogetInterfaceandRelease stream from a background thread and all works beautifully.

But for some reason, the C# can't even call back to C++ even from the 
original thread, let alone my background thread.

I am scratching my head from the past 2 or 3 days and tried all kinds of 
stuff but this beats me.

Any ideas? pointers? Perhaps I am doing something silly and stupid?

Comment: This might have to do with the .NET framework version you're targeting, as .NET will not make late-bound calls with `InterfaceIsDual` or `InterfaceIsIUnknown` interface definition, only with `dynamic` or reflection.

Answer (score 2):

IDispatch is designed for late-binding or "dynamic" dispatch. In this case, it appears you know the shape of the COM interface and already have an interop definition (CallBackInterface). So, instead of IDispatch you ought to be able to use IUnknown and set InterfaceType to InterfaceIsIUnknown.

Try that, and let us know if it worked.

If not, and you do in fact need to use IDispatch, then make sure your C++ object properly implements IDispatch (you'll need a type library and something like ATL's IDispatchImpl).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the post.
The C++ COM object is passing an IDispatch Interface pointer, 
but since I have the sources for the , I know that the Idispatch is actually a dual interface. So technically even if the C++ is passing 
an IDisapatch Interface, I should be able to freely cast it to 
a non IDispatch interface. (Dual) 

So I tried the trick of marshal as interface and declaring my interface as Dual (callbackinterface).

No matter what I do, I can't seem to find the method. and when I say 
it is a dual interface, why is it even looking for the get ids of names?????

Comment: But have you actually tried to pass it as `IUnknown` instead of `IDispatch` so that instead of late binding by names the call is made with early binding?

Comment: Ok So lets get this more concrete. 

Here is the actual interface defined in C++
`[uuid(....)]`
`interface IScanner : IDisapatch `
`{`
'    SOData (.... `
`}`

Comment: Sorry I am trying to see how to create a longer comment on this forum...
So Yes I tried marshaling as IUnknown. Same result.

Comment: That's odd because "GetIdsOfNames" is method on IDispatch implying that the CLR is trying dynamic dispatch (either because you declared it as such or because you're using 'dynamic').

Comment: Well, I declared the interface as MarshalAs.UnmanagedType.IDisapatch 
and then used Type.InvokeMember to call the IDispatch interface. Things seem to be working, although, I still see a first chance exception of 
NotImplemented exception coming from COmEventsSink.cs, but I guess since this is a first chance exception, I am going to ignore it, 
but I am very curious why in the first place there is even a first chance exception of not implemented exception when I am directly invoking the IDisapatch interface.